# Component not rendering while using route in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am rendering components according to authentication but after login redirection, only the navbar is displayed and the component is not at all rendered.

App.js

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        loggedIn,
        token,
        slrId,
        setLoggedIn,
        setUser,
        setToken,
        logout,
        setSlrId,
      }}
    >
      <Router>
      <MyAppBar />
       
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />

          <Route path="/login" exact render={() => <Auth path="login" />} />
          <Route path="/signup" exact render={() => <Auth path="signup" />} />
          {/* TODO:Add state change for customer and seller  */}
          <Route
            path="seller/login"
            exact
            render={() => <Auth path="seller/login" />}
          />

          <PrivateRoute path="seller/dashboard">
            <SellerDashBoard />
          </PrivateRoute>

        
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const {loggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        loggedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

It doesn't even redirect to login if not logged in.

Edit:
Added the dashboard file but I don't think so it is causing any problem.
But just to be sure I tested it on normal  it still didn't work so guess not the problem is it's not rendering on any routing method.

SelleDashboard.js

```
import React from 'react;
import {Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

const SellerDashBoard=(props)=>{
  return <Typography>seller dashboard</Typography>
}
export default SellerDashboard;
```

Comment: How do you make the redirect from login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am feeling really stupid posting it but anyhow the bug was due to the route path.
Turns out we need to add a '/' in front of them.
previously:-

```
<PrivateRoute path="seller/dashboard">
            <SellerDashBoard />
          </PrivateRoute>
```

now:-

```
<PrivateRoute path="/seller/dashboard">
            <SellerDashBoard />
          </PrivateRoute>
```

Answer (score 0):

can give me your github repo?without seeing in action i can't say anything and also attach your component code

Comment: sorry brother it's not public. just tell me what do you want to see.

Comment: give me the  <SellerDashBoard /> this part of the code

Comment: I added it. hope it helps.